# How take user input in one method and use it in another

Tags: java, methods

I am very new to java and have searched around and can't seem to find what to do.  I need to take int `number` and be able to use it in another method.  I have to use two methods to do this.  I am unsure how to call upon it.

---

```
public static void first()
{
    System.out.print("Enter number: ")
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = scan.nextInt();    
}

public static void getNumber(String name, int move)
{

    if (number == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Player shows one" );
    }
```

Comment: The naming of your methods is misleading, it's not clear what are you trying to do. (`getNumber` is not getting any numbers..)

Comment: You want to take input in one method and use that number as input in another method?

Comment: @user2181402 Try my answer it might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a method which return a number and call it from another method.

```
public static int first()
{
    System.out.print("Enter number: ")
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    return number;
}

public static void getNumber(String name, int move)
{
    int number = first();   //Call method here.
    if (number == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Player shows one" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define number as a class attribute.
Something like (its not final/working code)

```
class myClass{
  int number = 3;  // Or any other default value   

  public static void first()
  {
    //....
    obj.number = scan.nextInt();
    //...
  }  

 public static void getNumber(String name, int move)
 {
    if (obj.number == 1)
    {
       //...... 
    } 
 }

}
```

Comment: @Karna Still have problem Static method can not access direct instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

After `int number` call method

```
int number = scan.nextInt();
getNumber("Your Name", number);
```